# sql plus stored procedure for upsert

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm a complete novice and I'm asked to write stored procedure for upsert

I want to do the following:

```
exectute upsert(1,'locationA');
```

I google it and find :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_UPSERT (v_id IN NUMBER,
                                          v_searches IN VARCHAR2(20),
                                          v_account IN VARCHAR2(20)) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table (id, searches, account) VALUES (v_id, v_searches, v_account) ;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    UPDATE TABLE
    SET searches = v_searches, account = v_account
    WHERE id = v_id;
END;
/
```

Then I try to modify it to :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upsert (a IN NUMBER, b IN varchar(40) ) 
    AS
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO zone_location VALUES (a, b) ;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      UPDATE zone_location
      SET location = b
      WHERE zid = a;
    END;
    /
```

Even without the `EXCEPTION` part, I am told:
`PLS-00103`: Encounter the symbol `"("` when expecting ....

Thanks for your attention. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Oracle [MERGE](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g.php) is another option

Comment: I recommend you always list the columns in your INSERT statements, like this: `INSERT INTO zone_location (zid, location) VALUES (a, b) ;`

Comment: You misspelled execute

Answer (score 1):

Argument types do not require a size.  Change `VARCHAR2(20)` to `VARCHAR2`.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test_procedure(a varchar2)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.
```

The SQL*Plus error message includes a line and column number that help point to the problem.  Note that the column number is 36 characters but not counting the `create or replace`.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test_procedure(a varchar2(10))
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/36     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ) , @ % default character
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```